# Плеер по-разному работает на разных устройствах

Tags: ios, mediaplayer

Сделал аудиоплеер, работает на iPhone 5 и iPod отлично. Дал протестировать на iPhone 6 - песня не включается. В чем проблема? Разве на разных устройствах код выполняется по-разному?

```
 import UIKit
 import MediaPlayer
 import AVFoundation
 import CoreGraphics

 protocol PlayerDelegate : class {
   func soundFinished(sender : AnyObject)
 }


 class IpodMusicViewController: UIViewController, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var nameSound: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var speedometer: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var sliderVolume: UIView!


weak var delegate : PlayerDelegate?


@IBOutlet weak var headView: UIView!




var mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController?
var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?
var countItemSoung:Int = 0
var itemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Открыть библиотеку с музыкой
@IBAction func library(sender: AnyObject) {
    displayMediaPickerAndPlayItem()
}

//Создание mediaPicker
func displayMediaPickerAndPlayItem() {
    self.countItemSoung = 0
    self.mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .AnyAudio)
    if let picker = self.mediaPicker {
        print("Successfully instantiated a media picker")
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = true
        picker.showsCloudItems = true
        picker.prompt = "Pick a song please"
        presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        print("Could not instantiate a media picker")
    }
}

//Отображение mediaPicker
func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
    print("Media Picker returned")
    self.itemCollection = mediaItemCollection
    self.playMusic()
    self.nameSound.text = ""
    mediaPicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

//Закрыли mediaPicker
func mediaPickerDidCancel(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController) {
    if let picker = self.mediaPicker{
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}


//Создание объектов музыки и запуск трека
func playMusic () {
    let items = itemCollection!.items
    if (items.count > 0) {
        let itemTitle = itemCollection!.items[countItemSoung].valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as? String

        if items.count == 0 {
            mediaPicker!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        let item = items[countItemSoung]
        if let url: NSURL = item.assetURL {
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            }
            catch  {
                audioPlayer = nil
                mediaPicker!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                return
            }
            if let player = audioPlayer {
                audioPlayer?.delegate = self
                audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
                player.play()
            }
        }
        else {
            audioPlayer = nil
        }
    }
}

//Конец трека
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if flag && ((countItemSoung + 1) == itemCollection!.items.count) {
    }
    else {
        countItemSoung++
        playMusic()
    }
}


 }
```

Comment: Да, я просто удалил некоторый код, который не по сути. Там еще с локацией программа работает, сейчас подправлю

Comment: Тут и без лишних пустых строк кода очень много. Я, конечно, понимаю, что причина ошибки непонятна, но пробовали ли вы локализовать ошибку? Вряд ли найдётся много желающих перелопачивать весь код.

Comment: Нет, не пробовал, просто у меня iphone 5, приходятся заливать версию для testflight, чтобы отправить на iphone 6. Я сейчас попробую исключить максимум кода из сообщения

Comment: По крайней мере, если устройство в зоне вашей досягаемости - это уже лучше, чем "не работает где-то там, за пару тысяч километров",

Comment: какая версия iOS? и я предполагаю, что на эмуляторе iPhone6 работает отлично, раз вы пишете, что тестируете на девайсе?

Comment: Последняя - 9.02

Comment: App Transport Security отключили?

Comment: Нет, даже и не слышал про это никогда. А можете поподробнее рассказать что нужно сделать или ссылку дать?

Comment: В info.plis поместить это и тогда я отключу безопасность?

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
     <dict>  
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
     </dict>

Comment: Почитал при это ATS, разве он не только на HTTPS запросы влияет? Просто на iphone 5 с iOS 9.02 все работает(

Comment: тогда не оно. а что насчет эмулятора iPhone6, работает?

Comment: MediaPicker открывается, но там ведь нельзя работать с аудио, на сколько я знаю, там нет песен

Comment: можете в вопросе убрать весь код до минимального состояния, которое можно закинуть в пустой проект и посмотреть как оно себя ведет?

Comment: Да, конечно, несколько минут, спасибо

Comment: Сделал, нужно только одну кнопку на storyboard сделать "library", для открытия mediaPicker. Я могу сам собрать проект и прислать ссылку если так будет удобнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `MPMediaPickerController` показывает все песни, данного аккаунта, не зависимо от того, есть они на устройстве или нет. И если выбрана песня, которой на устройстве нет, `item.assetURL` приходит пустой. Чтобы с этим бороться можно:

- Отказаться от воспроизведения композиций, не присутствующих на устройстве. Для этого выставить `picker.showsCloudItems = false`, чтобы их вообще не было в списке.
- Заменить плеер на `MPMusicPlayerController`, который умеет загружать музыку из облака. Примерно так:

  ```
  audioPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
  audioPlayer?.setQueueWithItemCollection(itemCollection!)
  audioPlayer?.play()
  ```

Comment: Я сейчас попробую второй вариант реализовать, завтра отпишусь как все прошло. Я очень вам благодарен за помощь, уже не первый раз на этом сайте выручаете.

Comment: Первый вариант отказался работать, а вот второй вроде нормально работает, правда теперь я хочу изменить systemMusicPlayer, на applicationMusicPlayer(), но думаю, все будет работать. Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: @ed8009 странно, у меня первый работал. а вы где меняете? у вас там в одном месте создается не нужный референс на плеер `if let picker = self.mediaPicker` и уже в нем ставится `picker.showsCloudItems = true`. я там менял на `false`

Comment: и в этом коде второе условие не нужно `if (items.count > 0) { ... if items.count == 0 {`

Comment: Спасибо, я уже перебрал почти весь код и перешел на MPMusicPlayerController. И мне он нравится больше, удобно, не нужно  волноваться по поводу индекса песни, да и есть ряд других функций, которые сократились в плане кода

Comment: Появилась проблемка одна, причем опять на iphone 6 plus (на 5 работает нормально). Когда пользователь первый раз открывает приложение (удаляет и переустанавливает или когда обновление приходит) и выбирает проигрывать альбом, то ничего не происходит. Я вот думаю, может приложение просто видит обложку альбома, а сам он пустой, можно ли как-то в picker показывать только список песен без альбомов?

Comment: выносите в отдельный вопрос. будем разбиратсья

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, я тогда что-нибудь придумаю с реальным устройством, а то говорить о чем-то, используя симулятор не очень удобно